# WYSIWYG editor ruining my headlines

Tags: php, html

I just added WYSIWYG editor to my blog so I can easily post articles with text formatting. However, since I also got a box with recent posts, it automatically adds the text format (text bold, white lines etc) to those headlines. One headline contains the Title, abit of a content and the amount of reactions. Like:

BLOGTITLE
Abit of the article content
2 likes

Is there a way I could just show the content without the text formatting? I tried str_replace but that aint working for me. I also tried the striplashes. Doesnt work.

I dont think you need a piece of code since I'm simply echo'ing the message in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can!